# Strange behavior in a TVirtualStringTree

Tags: c++builder, tvirtualstringtree

Can someone explain to me why this is happening to me? I have this TVirtualStringTree:
[image: Text]

As you can see, three nodes have been selected. I traverse the tree to delete the selected records with this loop:

```
PVirtualNode Nodo;
AnsiString cAux = "";
Query->Close();
Query->SQL->Text = "DELETE FROM Recibos WHERE CodPrv = :PrvIns AND RefInt = :RefInt AND ForPago = :Forma AND Junta = :Junta";

Nodo = Lista->GetFirst();
while (Nodo != NULL)
{
     cAux = ((PTreeSelRec)Lista->GetNodeData(Nodo2))->Dato;
     if (!Lista->HasChildren[Nodo] && Lista->CheckState[Nodo] > csUncheckedPressed)
     {
          try
          {
               Query->Close();
               Query->ParamByName("PrvIns")->AsString = PrvIns;
               Query->ParamByName("RefInt")->AsString = ((PTreeSelRec)Lista->GetNodeData(Nodo))->RefInt;
               Query->ParamByName("Forma")->AsInteger = ((PTreeSelRec)Lista->GetNodeData(Nodo))->ForPago;
               Query->ParamByName("Junta")->AsInteger = StrToInt(((PTreeSelRec)Lista->GetNodeData(Nodo))->Concepto);
               Query->ExecSQL();
               Query->Transaction->Commit();
          }
          catch(...)
          {
               fForBln->Hide();
               Screen->Cursor = crArrow;
               Query->Transaction->Rollback();
               ShowMessage("Ha tenido lugar un error en el borrado de recibos.");
               Application->ProcessMessages();
               return;
          }
     }
     Nodo = Lista->GetNext(Nodo);
}
```

I have set up with the debugger to tell me the values of **HasChildren** and **CheckState**. At no time do I modify, as you can see, the CheckState property of the nodes; however, when I start traversing the tree, the HasChildren property gives me the correct values (three times true and once false) but CheckState, when it enters the last level of each node (Tomelloso in the example), is only set to 0 (csUncheckedNormal). This is what the debugger returns:

[image: Text]

As you can see, the first three times it takes the correct values: 10/01/2022, Ordinaries, Unknown. In all three cases HasChildren appears as true because in all three cases there is a child and CheckState as csCheckedNormal because the entire node is selected. But as soon as **List->GetNext(Node)** is done to take the *TOMELLOSO* value, without the code doing anything CheckState is set to csUncheckedNormal and, of course, the query is not executed.

I've tried forcing all nodes to expand (List->FullExpand()) but that doesn't work either; It only works well if before pressing the corresponding button the user manually displays the selected node, which is not very logical.

It seems that when the tree has more than three levels, not all nodes behave in the same way. What could I be doing wrong or what property of the object would I want to modify?

Comment: Just a thought, how is the tree being populated, is by sql query and does it update when records are deleted as you appear to do in your code in the while(nodo != NULL) it may be possible that the delete node code you have may need to be done in reverse order, that is start at the bottom child and work your way back to the parent node, this may be a case where deleting a vector element in a loop top to bottom loses its index value giving you the type of result you are getting.  Not saying this is the case just a thought as I have subclassed a treeview that can be filled by sql query

Comment: and use vectors to access the custom tree node properties, sometimes traversing the vector in reverse eliminates issues, good luck

Comment: First of all I'm using vectors to access node properties; the way the question was worded has an error.

Yes, the tree is filled by a query. The deletion is really done from the innermost level since these nodes contain all the properties that are later requested in the deletion query.

Thank you for your responses.